# Externally displayed Json Data not passed to reactjs components says error "embedded:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

My head is burning. For several hours of works am having the error below when passing externally retrieved json data to reactjs components
 here is the error
**embedded:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined**

below is the code. can someone help me fix the issue. I will appreciate any assistance no matter how little. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
var Test  = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <App/>
        );
    }
});


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super() 
      this.state = {
        data: []
      }

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "data1.json",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: 'json',
       ContentType: 'application/json',
       success: function(data) {

         var da = this.setState({data: data});
console.log(da);
       }.bind(this),
       error: function(jqXHR) {
         console.log(jqXHR);
       }.bind(this)
    })
  }


render(){
      return <p>The data is: {this.state.data}</p>;
  }

}


ReactDOM.render( <Test details={this.state.data}/>, document.getElementById( "content" ) );

</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

data1.json

```
[
            {
            no: "1",
            qtext:"sssssssCalifornia is in which part of USA?",
            options:[
                {text:"East"},
                {text:"Mid"},
                {text:"West"},
                {text:"South"}
            ],
            ans:"West",
            marks: 3
        },
        {
            no: "2",
            qtext:"Who is Prime Minister of India?",
            options:[
                {text:"Sonia Gandhi"},
                {text:"Narendra Modi"},
                {text:"Manmohan Singh"},
                {text:"Rahul Gandhi"}
            ],
            ans:"Narendra Modi",
            marks: 2
        },
        {
            no: "3",
            qtext:"Which of the following is most popular Search Engine Company?",
            options:[
                {text:"Microsoft"},
                {text:"Facebook"},
                {text:"Google"},
                {text:"Yahoo"}
            ],
            ans:"Google",
            marks: 1
        },
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get that error is because data is in fact not defined. As you can see, the data variable is defined inside the if-statement of the callback function, which is out of the scope of the React component.

Try declaring the data variable just after the script tag:

```
<script>
    var data;

    function loadJSON() {
    ...
</script>
```

and remove the var in front of data where it's value gets assigned (in the line var data=JSON.stringify(this.responseText);).

This however, will not solve your issues because the react component will never receive the value you are looking for. My recomendation is to move the data request (the loadJSON()) inside the react component, call it in the componentWillMount method of the react component and save the resulting data in the component's state. Something like:

```
class Test extends React.Component{

   constructor(){
       this.state = {};
   }

   componentWillMount(){

        this.loadJSON();
   }

   loadJSON() {
       var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
       var self = this;
       http.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               self.setState({data: JSON.parse(this.responseText)});
           }
       };
       http.open("GET", "data1.json", true);
       http.send();
  }

  render(){
      return <p>The data is: {this.state.data}</p>;
  }
}
```

Comment: i have followed your instruction and has re-write the code to implent react as you suggested but now it says error "embedded:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" please what could be the issue

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that happens because accessing this inside the anonymous function body re-defines this. I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: not working yet. please can you check my updated code

Comment: ReactDOM.render( <Test details={this.state.data}/>, document.getElementById( "content" ) );

There this will be undefined. You don't need to pass any argumetns to the React component, simply do: <Test />

Answer (score 0):

Use super(props) inside your constructor(props) to access this.state.

‘this’ keyword is uninitialized without calling super(props).

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={};
}
```